# How to recover data from query (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql

I've a problem when trying to get data back from a query. My user model is like this:

```
class UserModel extends DBAbstractModel {
 public $username;
 public $name; 
 public $surname; 
 public $country;

... More code

public function get($username='') { 
    if($username != ''): 
        $this->query = "SELECT Username,Name,Surname,Country,City 
            FROM user
            WHERE Username = '$username'"; 
        $this->get_results_from_query();        
    endif; 
    $res = count($this->rows);
    echo "Results found: $res<br>";
    if(count($this->rows) == 1): 
        foreach ($this->rows[0] as $propiedad=>$valor):             
            $this->$propiedad = $valor; 
        endforeach; 
    endif; 
}
```

I call the "get" method from other php that way:

```
require_once('usuarios_model.php');

$user = new UserModel(); 

$user->get('Hash'); 

print $user->name. ' ' . $user->surname . '<br>';
```

Well, my "Usermodel" brings 1 result back and if I include some "echo" tags I can see that its really bring information from database (name, surname, country ...). But the "print" tag of the calling php file is empty.

Does anyone knows whats going on?

Thank you.

Comment: Without posting the source of `DBAbstractModel` or at the very least `get_results_from_query` it will be impossible to answer your question

Comment: Try `echo '<pre>'.print_r($user, true).'</pre>;'` after `$user->get('Hash');`

Comment: Where are you filling the property values (name,surname, country...) at the top of the class?

Comment: Please lean how to use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). The code in current form is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Dunno why its important the code of DBAbstractModel if it returns properly the data of the user from the data base. I think the problem is that in `UserModel` the code `$this->$propiedad = $valor` is not setting the properties "name, surname, country..." and thats why i can't see them in the caller php file.

Comment: I tried `print_r($user, true)` and it returns `UserModel Object
(   [username] =>      
    [name] => 
    [surname] => 
    [country] =>    
    [db_name:protected] => dbName
    [query:protected] => SELECT      Username,Name,Surname,Country,City 
   FROM user
   WHERE Username = 'Hash'
    [rows:protected] => Array([0] => Array
                (                   
                    [Username] => Hash                    
                    [Name] => John
                    [Surname] => Connor
                    [Country] => Spain)

        )[conn:DBAbstractModel:private] => mysqli Object